# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined on tsx file

Tags: reactjs, typescript, asp.net-core-webapi, react-tsx

ActivityListItemAttendees

```
interface IProps {
    attendees: IAttendee[]
}

export const ActivityListItemAttendees: React.FC<IProps> = ({attendees}) => {
    return (
        <List horizontal>
            {attendees.map(attendee => (    
                <List.Item key={attendee.username}>
                    <h1>{attendee.displayName}</h1>
                </List.Item>
            ))}
        </List>
    );
}
```

ActivityListItem

```
const ActivityListItem: React.FC<{activity: IActivity}> = ({activity}) => {

    return (
        <Segment.Group>
            <Segment>
                <Item.Group>
                    <Item>
                        <Item.Image size='tiny' circular src='/items/user.png' />
                        <Item.Content>
                            <Item.Header as='a'>{activity.title}</Item.Header>
                            <Item.Meta>{format(activity.date, 'eeee do MMMM')}</Item.Meta>
                            <Item.Description>
                                Hosted By Bob
                            </Item.Description>
                        </Item.Content>
                    </Item>
                </Item.Group>
                </Segment>
                <Segment>
                    <Icon name='clock' /> {format(activity.date, 'h:mm a')}
                    <Icon name='marker' /> {activity.venue}, {activity.city}
                </Segment>
                <Segment secondary>
                    <ActivityListItemAttendees attendees = {activity.attendees} />
                </Segment>
                <Segment clearing>
                    <span>{activity.description}</span>
                    <Button
                        as={Link} to={`/activities/${activity.id}`}
                        floated='right'
                        content='View'
                        color='black' />
                </Segment>
        </Segment.Group>
    )
}

export default ActivityListItem
```

[Display Error Like these on Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0ThG.png)

I can't understand why Attendees can't read on browser? I added Interface on activity file. then I use it other's file as i'm done other's components
Please anyone help me out.

Their is Activity file how i declare. This file use in Create Activity, And Now On View Attendees

```
export interface IActivity {
    id: string;
    title: string;
    description: string;
    category: string;
    date: Date;
    city: string;
    venue: string;
    attendees: IAttendee[]
}

export interface IAttendee {
    username: string;
    displayName: string;
    image: string;
    isHost: boolean;
}
```

Comment: try `{attendees && attendees.map(attendee => ( `

Comment: also, before render, try to `console.log` it to see what it actually holds as data

Comment: @Apostolos thanks about Console.log. It seems Undefined. What should I do?

Comment: check my comment at my answer. :)

Comment: @Apostolos Can you check my Edited Post, I feel done already as you told.

Comment: then you need to check at `ActivityListItem` before render again via `console.log(activity)`. If this doesnt return the desired output, then you need to investigate further

Comment: @Apostolos I appreciate your help. Can you give me suggested website where i can get those answer to mapping [link](https://ibb.co/fkrdgmj) those data on browser. Attendees available as proxy object.

Comment: don't know such site, sorry :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing to check at same errors (not necessary though if you are 100% sure about the data):

```
export const ActivityListItemAttendees: React.FC<IProps> = ({attendees}) => {

console.log('What does actually attendees have?', attendees);
```

There are a lot of occasions where properties are at first undefined and after the second render they get their values.
In such cases, you need to check if they exist, and then use `map` in order to prevent these errors.

```
return (
    <List horizontal>
        {attendees && attendees.map(attendee => (
```

You can also use a loader component/loader text if this is not loaded yet.

Comment: as you suggest, Console say's "Undefined"

Comment: ok so then you need to go one level up and check `{activity.attendees}`